# Devise authorization error with the newest version of NoneSuch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

My controller has a devise authorization error that just started happening when I added the latest version of NoneSuch http://nonesuch.avdi.org

I'm on rails 2.3.6 and 1.1.6 devise. It happens even when I go to root_url without being logged in. I need a NoneSuch expert!

Answer (score 0):

It fixed in the new version of NoneSuch! Just update it.